# Does a foursquare like have a timestamp?

Tags: api, foursquare

Does a foursquare like have a timestamp?  Is this exposed anywhere?  I've got a great visualization idea that would depend on this data being made available.

I don't see this information in the venue likes endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not, unfortunately, expose the timestamp of when something was liked. It's a great idea though! I've discussed it with a few of the engineers here at foursquare, and it's definitely something we'd consider adding in the future (especially if more developers ask for it).